# Bash here document - suppress printing code to the screen?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am writing a script to become a user (let's call it genomics) via the cmd "sudo /etc/bgenomics" (this is setup by our admin) and run some bash code as that user, namely run a cmd, catch the exit code and take the appropriate action.

The problem is the bash code inside the here doc get printed to the screen, which is distracting and looks really unelegant.

Here's an illustration:

```
#!/bin/bash

name='George'

sudo /etc/bgenomics <<Q
/bin/bash
if (( 2 == 2 )); then
    echo "my name is $name"
    grep zzz /etc    # will return nothing and $? = 1
    echo \$?    # this should be 1 after the above cmd
fi
Q
```

The if statement is just there to show how annoying it is when printed.

Right now all of the following is printed to the screen:

```
Script started, file is /var/tmp/genomicstraces/c060644.20140617143003.11536
Script done, file is /var/tmp/genomicstraces/c060644.20140617143003.11536
brainiac-login-02$brainiac-login-02$/bin/bash
bash-3.2$ if (( 2 == 2 )); then
> echo "my name is George"
> grep zzz /etc    # will return nothing and 0 = 1
> echo $?    # this should be 1 after the above cmd
> fi
my name is George
1
```

The only parts I want to see are "my name is George" and "1".  Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Is another process calling this script? Output shouldn't normally appear unless bash is called with '-x'. Try modifying the first line of your script if you cannot disable echo in the calling process:

```
#!/bin/bash +x
```

You may also want to remove the call to /bin/bash after the sudo command unless you really wish to start another shell within your shell.

Comment: I run this script directly from the cmd line.  No difference with +x.  I'm calling bash explicitly b/c my default shell is csh.

Answer (score 1):

The here document supplies input to the `bgenomics` script via its standard input. What happens to that input is up to that script.

If you want the script to print some of its input, and not print some of its input, you have to modify the script.

If `bgenomics` is actually a wrapper for an interactive shell session (as it seems to be, judging by the `Script started` and `Script done` traces), then here documents are not the best way to feed input into it.

A good way is to use the `expect` utility, which controls interactive programs via a pseudo-terminal device and provides a scripting language with a great deal of control. `expect` can suppress all unwanted input from an interactive program.  It can look for specific outputs from the program, and supply responses. For instance it can look for a `login:` string coming from the interactive session, and send a user name.

Answer (score 1):

The program `bgenomics` has an invocation of `script` in it to record what the script did. Talk to the person in charge of that to understand what their intentions are. Until you understand the purpose of `bgenomics` you risk screwing up what the author of that is trying to do.

```
$ script /tmp/junk.txt
Script started, file is /tmp/junk.txt
$ date            # this is a child shell of the script command
Tue Jun 17 21:04:14 EDT 2014
$ exit
Script done, file is /tmp/junk.txt
```